# SDImage - caching error with new public ec2 address

Tags: ios, swift, caching, amazon-ec2, image-caching

I recently reverted my mobile iOS app to a new public EC2 instance. I changed all records of the old public address to the new address, including the app delegate of course.

However, there are still records showing on the console referring back to the old ec2. Specifically, when I fetch SDImage functions.

Here are my current functions:

```swift
extension UITableViewCell {
    func loadImageWith(imgView: UIImageView, url: String?) {
        print("UITableViewCell - Attempting to load image with URL: \(url ?? "")")

        imgView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
        imgView.sd_imageIndicator?.startAnimatingIndicator()

        // Clear SDWebImage cache
        SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()
        SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()

        if let imageUrl = URL(string: url ?? "") {
            imgView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: nil, options: [.scaleDownLargeImages], completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("UITableViewCell - Error loading image: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                    imgView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultPropic")
                }
            })
        } else {
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultPropic")
        }
    }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell {
    func loadImageWith(imgView: UIImageView, url: String?) {
        print("UICollectionViewCell - Attempting to load image with URL: \(url ?? "")")

        imgView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
        imgView.sd_imageIndicator?.startAnimatingIndicator()

        // Clear SDWebImage cache
        SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()
        SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()

        if let imageUrl = URL(string: url ?? "") {
            imgView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: nil, options: [.scaleDownLargeImages], completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("UICollectionViewCell - Error loading image: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                    imgView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultPropic")
                }
            })
        } else {
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultPropic")
        }
    }
}
```

And the console prints something like this:

```
 UITableViewCell - Attempting to load image with URL: ["Old EC2 Instance request"]

 [Date & Time] Task <926D5F8F-3200-498D-A60B-
F9D0C15C812E>.<28> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x281a25d40 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "
(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, 
_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <926D5F8F-3200-498D-A60B-
F9D0C15C812E>.<28>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <926D5F8F-3200-498D-A60B-F9D0C15C812E>.<28>"
 ), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=["Old
 EC2 Instance request"], NSErrorFailingURLKey=["Old EC2 Instance request"]}
 UITableViewCell - Error loading image: The request timed out
```

Comment: I have temporarily solved this by running an if statement, if the old ec2 is present replace it with the new in each of these above functions and it is working...